# Compatibility between QuickFIX and QuickFIX/N engines

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I want to use .NET-based QuickFIX/N(v4.4) engine as client(initiator）to establish connection with FXCM QuickFIX(v4.4) server(acceptor) and conduct various trading request.

Are both FIX engines fully compatible with each other？Would anybody share related experience?

Answer (score 2):

Please don't confuse the implementation with the protocol. The underlying protocol is the FIX Protocol which is supported by every FIX engine.

So yes, both FIX engines are compatible with each other.

Comment: hi,Christoph. i will  have a try on connection between fix and fix/n. so, thanks for your clearance of my doubts on this issue.